# Most effecient way to Optimize Index Match Problem in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet in excel that tracks the amount of open futures contracts for the closest contract available (Seen in Column C). In column E, I'm also tracking the number of days left until that contract expires.

What I'm trying to do is populate a table that will pull the historical Open interest for each month and year that I have data for that is the closest match to the current days days to expirty. Essentially trying to get a snapshot of every month with the same number of days until expiry. So for example, right now there are 11 days until expiry for the current contract. I'd like to pull amount of open interest (value in column C) in Jan2019 when there were 11 days before expiry, in Feb2019 when there were 11 days to expiry and so on and so forth. I have about 5 years worth of data.

I've made a blank shell of the table to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

### [image]

**What I've Tried:**

---

So far I've tried adding the code column you see in column F.

Then:
1. I tried to find the row where the month/year combo of that cell begins by using `match` and looking for the first exact appearance of that date month combo. 
2. I tried to find the row where the last month/year combo is by using a `sumproduct`:

`SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(Sheet1!AP:AP)*(Sheet1!AP:AP='Sheet1 (2)'!$E$3)`

where sheet1(2)E3 was equal to the month year combo. 
3. Then I used `indirect` to create the range for that month/year combo start and end and did another `index` `match` set which uses that range and searches for the closest days till expiry in that range.

It works but what I'm left with his this horribly convoluted formula that is very difficult to follow and very slow.

```
    =INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet1!AY"&MATCH('Sheet1 (2)'!$E$3,Sheet1!AP:AP,0)&":AY"&
SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(Sheet1!AP:AP)*(Sheet1!AP:AP='Sheet1 (2)'!$E$3)))),
MATCH($C$3,INDIRECT("Sheet1!AM"&
MATCH('Sheet1 (2)'!$E$3,Sheet1!$AP:$AP,0)&":AM"&
SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(Sheet1!$AP:$AP)*(Sheet1!$AP:$AP='Sheet1 (2)'!$E$3)))),0))
```

I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on a more efficient way to tackle this problem?

ive attached a small sample in case anyone need to work in excel as well as a image of my sheet so you can see the shell of the table I'm attempting to create.

```
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+------------------+--------+
|   Date    | Contract |    OI    |   COD    | Days Till Expiry |  code  |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+------------------+--------+
| 3-Jan-19  | FEB      | 378,871  | (2,673)  |               28 |  20191 |
| 4-Jan-19  | FEB      | 367,400  | (11,471) |               27 |  20191 |
| 7-Jan-19  | FEB      | 361,363  | (6,037)  |               24 |  20191 |
| 8-Jan-19  | FEB      | 329,416  | (31,947) |               23 |  20191 |
| 9-Jan-19  | FEB      | 290,508  | (38,908) |               22 |  20191 |
| 10-Jan-19 | FEB      | 260,311  | (30,197) |               21 |  20191 |
| 11-Jan-19 | FEB      | 216,583  | (43,728) |               20 |  20191 |
| 14-Jan-19 | FEB      | 176,807  | (39,776) |               17 |  20191 |
| 15-Jan-19 | FEB      | 145,033  | (31,774) |               16 |  20191 |
| 16-Jan-19 | FEB      | 89,777   | (55,256) |               15 |  20191 |
| 17-Jan-19 | FEB      | 61,293   | (28,484) |               14 |  20191 |
| 18-Jan-19 | FEB      | 25,682   | (35,611) |               13 |  20191 |
| 22-Jan-19 | MAR      | 499,043  | (6,558)  |                9 |  20191 |
| 23-Jan-19 | MAR      | 496,877  | (2,166)  |                8 |  20191 |
| 24-Jan-19 | MAR      | 481,966  | (14,911) |                7 |  20191 |
| 25-Jan-19 | MAR      | 471,888  | (10,078) |                6 |  20191 |
| 28-Jan-19 | MAR      | 469,447  | (2,441)  |                3 |  20191 |
| 29-Jan-19 | MAR      | 464,251  | (5,196)  |                2 |  20191 |
| 30-Jan-19 | MAR      | 466,044  | 1,793    |                1 |  20191 |
| 31-Jan-19 | MAR      | 463,779  | (2,265)  |               28 |  20191 |
| 1-Feb-19  | MAR      | 457,940  | (5,839)  |               27 |  20192 |
| 4-Feb-19  | MAR      | 441,710  | (16,230) |               24 |  20192 |
| 5-Feb-19  | MAR      | 431,584  | (10,126) |               23 |  20192 |
| 6-Feb-19  | MAR      | 413,688  | (17,896) |               22 |  20192 |
| 7-Feb-19  | MAR      | 371,226  | (42,462) |               21 |  20192 |
| 8-Feb-19  | MAR      | 318,986  | (52,240) |               20 |  20192 |
| 11-Feb-19 | MAR      | 264,681  | (54,305) |               17 |  20192 |
| 12-Feb-19 | MAR      | 223,779  | (40,902) |               16 |  20192 |
| 13-Feb-19 | MAR      | 163,621  | (60,158) |               15 |  20192 |
| 14-Feb-19 | MAR      | 109,346  | (54,275) |               14 |  20192 |
| 15-Feb-19 | MAR      | 74,706   | (34,640) |               13 |  20192 |
| 19-Feb-19 | MAR      | 29,785   | (44,921) |                9 |  20192 |
| 20-Feb-19 | APR      | 407,691  | 8,288    |                8 |  20192 |
| 21-Feb-19 | APR      | 400,292  | (7,399)  |                7 |  20192 |
| 22-Feb-19 | APR      | 399,406  | (886)    |                6 |  20192 |
| 25-Feb-19 | APR      | 387,301  | (12,105) |                3 |  20192 |
| 26-Feb-19 | APR      | 382,166  | (5,135)  |                2 |  20192 |
| 27-Feb-19 | APR      | 383,252  | 1,086    |                1 |  20192 |
| 28-Feb-19 | APR      | 377,617  | (5,635)  |               29 |  20192 |
| 1-Mar-19  | APR      | 368,105  | (9,512)  |               28 |  20193 |
| 4-Mar-19  | APR      | 358,824  | (9,281)  |               25 |  20193 |
| 5-Mar-19  | APR      | 353,287  | (5,537)  |               24 |  20193 |
| 6-Mar-19  | APR      | 332,570  | (20,717) |               23 |  20193 |
| 7-Mar-19  | APR      | 294,866  | (37,704) |               22 |  20193 |
| 8-Mar-19  | APR      | 252,613  | (42,253) |               21 |  20193 |
| 11-Mar-19 | APR      | 215,862  | (36,751) |               18 |  20193 |
| 12-Mar-19 | APR      | 184,451  | (31,411) |               17 |  20193 |
| 13-Mar-19 | APR      | 161,079  | (23,372) |               16 |  20193 |
| 14-Mar-19 | APR      | 134,939  | (26,140) |               15 |  20193 |
| 15-Mar-19 | APR      | 98,719   | (36,220) |               14 |  20193 |
| 18-Mar-19 | APR      | 67,480   | (31,239) |               11 |  20193 |
| 19-Mar-19 | APR      | 18,770   | (48,710) |               10 |  20193 |
| 20-Mar-19 | MAY      | 435,389  | (301)    |                9 |  20193 |
| 21-Mar-19 | MAY      | 434,375  | (1,014)  |                8 |  20193 |
| 22-Mar-19 | MAY      | 426,723  | (7,652)  |                7 |  20193 |
| 25-Mar-19 | MAY      | 423,515  | (3,208)  |                4 |  20193 |
| 26-Mar-19 | MAY      | 422,471  | (1,044)  |                3 |  20193 |
| 27-Mar-19 | MAY      | 409,365  | (13,106) |                2 |  20193 |
| 28-Mar-19 | MAY      | 401,827  | (7,538)  |                1 |  20193 |
| 29-Mar-19 | MAY      | 403,676  | 1,849    |               32 |  20193 |
| 1-Apr-19  | MAY      | 405,918  | 2,242    |               29 |  20194 |
| 2-Apr-19  | MAY      | 391,777  | (14,141) |               28 |  20194 |
| 3-Apr-19  | MAY      | 374,802  | (16,975) |               27 |  20194 |
| 4-Apr-19  | MAY      | 361,966  | (12,836) |               26 |  20194 |
| 5-Apr-19  | MAY      | 346,628  | (15,338) |               25 |  20194 |
| 8-Apr-19  | MAY      | 318,369  | (28,259) |               22 |  20194 |
| 9-Apr-19  | MAY      | 280,173  | (38,196) |               21 |  20194 |
| 10-Apr-19 | MAY      | 257,042  | (23,131) |               20 |  20194 |
| 11-Apr-19 | MAY      | 218,311  | (38,731) |               19 |  20194 |
| 12-Apr-19 | MAY      | 196,720  | (21,591) |               18 |  20194 |
| 15-Apr-19 | MAY      | 162,601  | (34,119) |               15 |  20194 |
| 16-Apr-19 | MAY      | 98,193   | (64,408) |               14 |  20194 |
| 17-Apr-19 | MAY      | 72,280   | (25,913) |               13 |  20194 |
| 18-Apr-19 | MAY      | 22,036   | (50,244) |               12 |  20194 |
| 22-Apr-19 | JUN      | 477,250  | 16,318   |                8 |  20194 |
| 23-Apr-19 | JUN      | 473,277  | (3,973)  |                7 |  20194 |
| 24-Apr-19 | JUN      | 473,594  | 317      |                6 |  20194 |
| 25-Apr-19 | JUN      | 459,817  | (13,777) |                5 |  20194 |
| 26-Apr-19 | JUN      | 456,552  | (3,265)  |                4 |  20194 |
| 29-Apr-19 | JUN      | 446,583  | (9,969)  |                1 |  20194 |
| 30-Apr-19 | JUN      | 439,249  | (7,334)  |               31 |  20194 |
| 1-May-19  | JUN      | 431,230  | (8,019)  |               30 |  20195 |
| 2-May-19  | JUN      | 420,813  | (10,417) |               29 |  20195 |
| 3-May-19  | JUN      | 394,652  | (26,161) |               28 |  20195 |
| 6-May-19  | JUN      | 384,049  | (10,603) |               25 |  20195 |
| 7-May-19  | JUN      | 347,698  | (36,351) |               24 |  20195 |
| 8-May-19  | JUN      | 315,442  | (32,256) |               23 |  20195 |
| 9-May-19  | JUN      | 292,022  | (23,420) |               22 |  20195 |
| 10-May-19 | JUN      | 261,381  | (30,641) |               21 |  20195 |
| 13-May-19 | JUN      | 229,525  | (31,856) |               18 |  20195 |
| 14-May-19 | JUN      | 203,905  | (25,620) |               17 |  20195 |
| 15-May-19 | JUN      | 166,034  | (37,871) |               16 |  20195 |
| 16-May-19 | JUN      | 98,367   | (67,667) |               15 |  20195 |
| 17-May-19 | JUN      | 66,762   | (31,605) |               14 |  20195 |
| 20-May-19 | JUN      | 20,690   | (46,072) |               11 |  20195 |
| 21-May-19 | JUL      | 441,614  | (5,739)  |               10 |  20195 |
| 22-May-19 | JUL      | 441,633  | 19       |                9 |  20195 |
| 23-May-19 | JUL      | 438,307  | (3,326)  |                8 |  20195 |
| 24-May-19 | JUL      | 427,918  | (10,389) |                7 |  20195 |
| 28-May-19 | JUL      | 412,018  | (15,900) |                3 |  20195 |
| 29-May-19 | JUL      | 382,277  | (29,741) |                2 |  20195 |
| 30-May-19 | JUL      | 376,374  | (5,903)  |                1 |  20195 |
| 31-May-19 | JUL      | 368,466  | (7,908)  |               28 |  20195 |
| 3-Jun-19  | JUL      | 366,193  | (2,273)  |               25 |  20196 |
| 4-Jun-19  | JUL      | 363,046  | (3,147)  |               24 |  20196 |
| 5-Jun-19  | JUL      | 362,201  | (845)    |               23 |  20196 |
| 6-Jun-19  | JUL      | 343,970  | (18,231) |               22 |  20196 |
| 7-Jun-19  | JUL      | 308,942  | (35,028) |               21 |  20196 |
| 10-Jun-19 | JUL      | 272,110  | (36,832) |               18 |  20196 |
| 11-Jun-19 | JUL      | 237,203  | (34,907) |               17 |  20196 |
| 12-Jun-19 | JUL      | 203,403  | (33,800) |               16 |  20196 |
| 13-Jun-19 | JUL      | 157,857  | (45,546) |               15 |  20196 |
| 14-Jun-19 | JUL      | 128,496  | (29,361) |               14 |  20196 |
| 17-Jun-19 | JUL      | 79,872   | (48,624) |               11 |  20196 |
| 18-Jun-19 | JUL      | 54,119   | (25,753) |               10 |  20196 |
| 19-Jun-19 | JUL      | 21,321   | (32,798) |                9 |  20196 |
| 20-Jun-19 | AUG      | 347,579  | 4,288    |                8 |  20196 |
| 21-Jun-19 | AUG      | 345,680  | (1,899)  |                7 |  20196 |
| 24-Jun-19 | AUG      | 341,183  | (4,497)  |                4 |  20196 |
| 25-Jun-19 | AUG      | 338,117  | (3,066)  |                3 |  20196 |
| 26-Jun-19 | AUG      | 338,300  | 183      |                2 |  20196 |
| 27-Jun-19 | AUG      | 334,543  | (3,757)  |                1 |  20196 |
| 28-Jun-19 | AUG      | 328,837  | (5,706)  |               33 |  20196 |
| 1-Jul-19  | AUG      | 319,323  | (9,514)  |               30 |  20197 |
| 2-Jul-19  | AUG      | 313,008  | (6,315)  |               29 |  20197 |
| 3-Jul-19  | AUG      | 299,915  | (13,093) |               28 |  20197 |
| 5-Jul-19  | AUG      | 289,164  | (10,751) |               26 |  20197 |
| 8-Jul-19  | AUG      | 262,191  | (26,973) |               23 |  20197 |
| 9-Jul-19  | AUG      | 234,613  | (27,578) |               22 |  20197 |
| 10-Jul-19 | AUG      | 215,505  | (19,108) |               21 |  20197 |
| 11-Jul-19 | AUG      | 199,666  | (15,839) |               20 |  20197 |
| 12-Jul-19 | AUG      | 179,768  | (19,898) |               19 |  20197 |
| 15-Jul-19 | AUG      | 147,999  | (31,769) |               16 |  20197 |
| 16-Jul-19 | AUG      | 119,793  | (28,206) |               15 |  20197 |
| 17-Jul-19 | AUG      | 83,809   | (35,984) |               14 |  20197 |
| 18-Jul-19 | AUG      | 55,908   | (27,901) |               13 |  20197 |
| 19-Jul-19 | AUG      | 19,557   | (36,351) |               12 |  20197 |
| 22-Jul-19 | SEP      | 438,301  | 391      |                9 |  20197 |
| 23-Jul-19 | SEP      | 431,404  | (6,897)  |                8 |  20197 |
| 24-Jul-19 | SEP      | 421,203  | (10,201) |                7 |  20197 |
| 25-Jul-19 | SEP      | 417,324  | (3,879)  |                6 |  20197 |
| 26-Jul-19 | SEP      | 410,680  | (6,644)  |                5 |  20197 |
| 29-Jul-19 | SEP      | 411,795  | 1,115    |                2 |  20197 |
| 30-Jul-19 | SEP      | 406,009  | (5,786)  |                1 |  20197 |
| 31-Jul-19 | SEP      | 402,392  | (3,617)  |               30 |  20197 |
| 1-Aug-19  | SEP      | 403,715  | 1,323    |               29 |  20198 |
| 2-Aug-19  | SEP      | 399,849  | (3,866)  |               28 |  20198 |
| 5-Aug-19  | SEP      | 384,410  | (15,439) |               25 |  20198 |
| 6-Aug-19  | SEP      | 381,492  | (2,918)  |               24 |  20198 |
| 7-Aug-19  | SEP      | 344,560  | (36,932) |               23 |  20198 |
| 8-Aug-19  | SEP      | 301,000  | (43,560) |               22 |  20198 |
| 9-Aug-19  | SEP      | 266,871  | (34,129) |               21 |  20198 |
| 12-Aug-19 | SEP      | 227,125  | (39,746) |               18 |  20198 |
| 13-Aug-19 | SEP      | 174,139  | (52,986) |               17 |  20198 |
| 14-Aug-19 | SEP      | 137,250  | (36,889) |               16 |  20198 |
| 15-Aug-19 | SEP      | 100,019  | (37,231) |               15 |  20198 |
| 16-Aug-19 | SEP      | 82,935   | (17,084) |               14 |  20198 |
| 19-Aug-19 | SEP      | 34,638   | (48,297) |               11 |  20198 |
| 20-Aug-19 | OCT      | 369,434  | (13,140) |               10 |  20198 |
| 21-Aug-19 | OCT      | 366,408  | (3,026)  |                9 |  20198 |
| 22-Aug-19 | OCT      | 361,189  | (5,219)  |                8 |  20198 |
| 23-Aug-19 | OCT      | 359,507  | (1,682)  |                7 |  20198 |
| 26-Aug-19 | OCT      | 362,457  | 2,950    |                4 |  20198 |
| 27-Aug-19 | OCT      | 369,335  | 6,878    |                3 |  20198 |
| 28-Aug-19 | OCT      | 373,402  | 4,067    |                2 |  20198 |
| 29-Aug-19 | OCT      | 370,192  | (3,210)  |                1 |  20198 |
| 30-Aug-19 | OCT      | 372,871  | 2,679    |               31 |  20198 |
| 3-Sep-19  | OCT      | 370,141  | (2,730)  |               27 |  20199 |
| 4-Sep-19  | OCT      | 351,755  | (18,386) |               26 |  20199 |
| 5-Sep-19  | OCT      | 319,489  | (32,266) |               25 |  20199 |
| 6-Sep-19  | OCT      | 299,951  | (19,538) |               24 |  20199 |
| 9-Sep-19  | OCT      | 265,327  | (34,624) |               21 |  20199 |
| 10-Sep-19 | OCT      | 227,421  | (37,906) |               20 |  20199 |
| 11-Sep-19 | OCT      | 191,570  | (35,851) |               19 |  20199 |
| 12-Sep-19 | OCT      | 159,934  | (31,636) |               18 |  20199 |
| 13-Sep-19 | OCT      | 138,296  | (21,638) |               17 |  20199 |
| 16-Sep-19 | OCT      | 80,041   | (58,255) |               14 |  20199 |
| 17-Sep-19 | OCT      | 59,406   | (20,635) |               13 |  20199 |
| 18-Sep-19 | OCT      | 20,475   | (38,931) |               12 |  20199 |
| 19-Sep-19 | NOV      | 412,945  | 31,478   |               11 |  20199 |
| 20-Sep-19 | NOV      | 411,387  | (1,558)  |               10 |  20199 |
| 23-Sep-19 | NOV      | 406,079  | (5,308)  |                7 |  20199 |
| 24-Sep-19 | NOV      | 404,106  | (1,973)  |                6 |  20199 |
| 25-Sep-19 | NOV      | 390,178  | (13,928) |                5 |  20199 |
| 26-Sep-19 | NOV      | 384,036  | (6,142)  |                4 |  20199 |
| 27-Sep-19 | NOV      | 380,790  | (3,246)  |                3 |  20199 |
| 30-Sep-19 | NOV      | 384,034  | 3,244    |               31 |  20199 |
| 1-Oct-19  | NOV      | 385,741  | 1,707    |               30 | 201910 |
| 2-Oct-19  | NOV      | 387,010  | 1,269    |               29 | 201910 |
| 3-Oct-19  | NOV      | 391,826  | 4,816    |               28 | 201910 |
| 4-Oct-19  | NOV      | 388,735  | (3,091)  |               27 | 201910 |
| 7-Oct-19  | NOV      | 353,392  | (35,343) |               24 | 201910 |
| 8-Oct-19  | NOV      | 303,430  | (49,962) |               23 | 201910 |
| 9-Oct-19  | NOV      | 258,642  | (44,788) |               22 | 201910 |
| 10-Oct-19 | NOV      | 224,022  | (34,620) |               21 | 201910 |
| 11-Oct-19 | NOV      | 182,895  | (41,127) |               20 | 201910 |
| 14-Oct-19 | NOV      | 167,983  | (14,912) |               17 | 201910 |
| 15-Oct-19 | NOV      | 147,337  | (20,646) |               16 | 201910 |
| 16-Oct-19 | NOV      | 121,704  | (25,633) |               15 | 201910 |
| 17-Oct-19 | NOV      | 79,987   | (41,717) |               14 | 201910 |
| 18-Oct-19 | NOV      | 54,642   | (25,345) |               13 | 201910 |
| 21-Oct-19 | NOV      | 31,545   | (23,097) |               10 | 201910 |
| 22-Oct-19 | DEC      | 455,595  | 6,296    |                9 | 201910 |
| 23-Oct-19 | DEC      | 449,370  | (6,225)  |                8 | 201910 |
| 24-Oct-19 | DEC      | 444,100  | (5,270)  |                7 | 201910 |
| 25-Oct-19 | DEC      | 443,839  | (261)    |                6 | 201910 |
| 28-Oct-19 | DEC      | 435,704  | (8,135)  |                3 | 201910 |
| 29-Oct-19 | DEC      | 426,782  | (8,922)  |                2 | 201910 |
| 30-Oct-19 | DEC      | 412,326  | (14,456) |                1 | 201910 |
| 31-Oct-19 | DEC      | 404,468  | (7,858)  |               29 | 201910 |
| 5-Nov-19  | DEC      | 396,111  | (8,357)  |               24 | 201911 |
| 6-Nov-19  | DEC      | 370,659  | (25,452) |               23 | 201911 |
| 7-Nov-19  | DEC      | 352,623  | (18,036) |               22 | 201911 |
| 8-Nov-19  | DEC      | 317,524  | (35,099) |               21 | 201911 |
| 11-Nov-19 | DEC      | 280,522  | (37,002) |               18 | 201911 |
| 12-Nov-19 | DEC      | 223,814  | (56,708) |               17 | 201911 |
| 13-Nov-19 | DEC      | 195,205  | (28,609) |               16 | 201911 |
| 14-Nov-19 | DEC      | 152,910  | (42,295) |               15 | 201911 |
| 15-Nov-19 | DEC      | 99,745   | (53,165) |               14 | 201911 |
| 18-Nov-19 | DEC      | 67,327   | (32,418) |               11 | 201911 |
| 19-Nov-19 | DEC      | 23,223   | (44,104) |               10 | 201911 |
| 20-Nov-19 | JAN      | 456,531  | (14,092) |                9 | 201911 |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My first try (not the answer, works only with at least one record per date)**

<del>If the combination of year/month/days till expiry is unique you can use this formular for `J10`:</del>

<del>`=SUMPRODUCT(N($I10=YEAR($A$2:$A$99));N(J$9=MONTH($A$2:$A$99));N($J$5=$E$2:$E$99);$C$2:$C$99)`</del>

<del>Since I didn't know where your data ends I limited the ranges to row `99`. You may edit that number to the last line of data. Furthermore you may copy and paste the formular from `J10` to the whole desired range (up to `U13` as far as I can see).</del>

<del>Note that if the combination of year/month/days till expiry is *not* unique (i.e. you have more than one row for a given combination) then all OI values of that rows are summed up</del>.

---

**My second try**

I had a similar case some years ago and after searching some minutes I found the old Excel file and could transform my old solution to match your scenario.

Again, based on your screenshot you can copy the following formular to cell `J10`

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(N(NUMBERVALUE($I10&""&J$9)=$F$2:$F$999),N($E$2:$E$999=MIN(IF(N(NUMBERVALUE($I10&""&J$9)=$F$2:$F$999)*N($J$5<=$E$2:$E$999)>0,$E$2:$E$999,99999))),$C$2:$C$999)}
```

Note that you do not copy the enclosing brackets (`{` and `}`). Instead paste the formular to cell `J10` and complete your input with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`. Then you may copy the formular from `J10` to the whole range up to `U13`. You may adjust all appearances of `999` to the maximum row number of your data.

Finally, I try to give a minimal explanation of the parts of the `SUMPRODUCT`:

1) Compare year/month with current values (years in column `I`, months in row `9`)

```
N(NUMBERVALUE($I10&""&J$9)=$F$2:$F$999)
```

2) Find the row with the minimal expiry value of those rows with an expiry value greater than or equal to the searched value (cell `J5`)

```
N($E$2:$E$999=MIN(IF(N(NUMBERVALUE($I10&""&J$9)=$F$2:$F$999)*N($J$5<=$E$2:$E$999)>0,$E$2:$E$999,99999)))
```

3) The OI value

```
$C$2:$C$999
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Yes, they are unique. There is only 1 day per expiry for each day per month per year. How will this it if there is no exact match. For example the there might be 10 days till expiry but last month, the 10th day would've fallen on a weekend so I'd need it to pick the 11th day instead.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly. I assumed at least one record/row for each date.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to try anyway!